# When running SharePoint solution deployment through a remote shell, solution deployment hangs

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, deployment, sharepoint-2010, remoting

I have a remote shell (using PowerShell) running a solution deployment on SharePoint 2010. It hangs on the deployment and never finishes deploying. When I do this locally from the box, there are no issues deploying.

I thought originally that this could have to do with paging due to the remote shell memory limit (which is, by default, 512MB). I increased that to 2 GB:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048
```

This hasn't made any difference. I also ensure that the SharePoint Administration and Timer Service are started before attempting to deploy. Also, the credentials I have used to open the remote shell are for the farm account.

What would cause a solution deployment to hang only when run through a remote shell?

Answer (score 0):

I attempted the same thing recently and found that remote shells have a limited amount of access to the remote environment depending on the credential provider used.  Security policies inhibit some IO operations with the file system, etc. I was able to work around this leveraging a package management solution such as Chocolatey.org, which can kick off powershell commands in another process on the remote box, but from what I understand of the issue, it's a Double Hop credential problem that can be solved using CredSSP when establishing the remote connection.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I should have mentioned we have CredSSP set up due to encountering the Double Hop issue before. The problem turned out to be the admin service on one of our WFEs that was not started for whatever reason.